# Sql query not working in Visual Studio 2010 report

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, report, window-functions

I have some problems with a report in Visual Studio 2010.
I made a query in PostgreSQL that works fine when I run it in pgAdmin Sql Editor, however after I make a new Dataset and TableAdapter in VS2010 and add the query in Query Builder, I get the following error.

```
Error in list of function arguments: '(' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: ')' not recognized.
Error in WHERE clause near '1 months'.
Unable to parse query text.
```

If I hit execute query, it returns the following error:

```
ERROR[42704]ERROR:type "INTERVAL" does not exists;
```

If I remove the double quotes that VS2010 is adding itself around "INTERVAL" and hit execute query again, it works but as soon as I hit OK, the quotes appear again. All that being said, if I right click the TableAdapter and hit Preview Data, the result is fine.

Now if I make a report and add the above DataSet then make a WindowForm and add a ReportViewer connected to report, when I run it, nothing happens; all stays blank.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT prod, mod, piece, no,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY mod ORDER BY no DESC)
FROM (SELECT prod, mod, piece,
               COUNT(qty) AS no
               FROM com c 
                     INNER JOIN lines l ON c.idcom=l.idcom
                     INNER JOIN pieces p ON l.idpiece=p.idpiece
                     INNER JOIN models m ON p.idmodel=m.idmodel
                     INNER JOIN prods pr ON m.idprod=pr.idprod
                WHERE c.date >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'
                GROUP BY piece,mod,prod) AS foo
```

I don't understand why if I Preview Data from the DataSet, the query runs fine(with all those parsing errors) but if I add it to the report, nothing happens. If you need more details, please ask. Thank you.

Comment: If you say `interval '1 months'` then maybe the quoting problem will go away, `"interval" '1 months'` is okay but `"INTERVAL" '1 months'` is not. I have no idea what VS is on about with parentheses though.

Comment: You are right. Using lowercase "interval" solved the ERROR[42704] when I hit Execute Query but everything else stays the same. Still no data in the report.

Comment: Use `INTERVAL '1' MONTH`. As for the parens, I suspect that whatever tool you are using is choking on the window function. You might need to hide the details of the query from its parser using a view or SQL function defined in the database.